# Why does unsigned 3-bit bitfield wrap around -7 to 1

Tags: c, bit-fields, qualifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test{
   unsigned int a:3;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct test b;
  b.a = -7; // implicit truncation to 1
  return 0;
}
```

-7 is a four bit number represented as 1111. Now my bitfield takes only 3 bits and has the unsigned qualifier. As per my knowledge unsigned 3 bit integers range from 0-7. Following this assumption, I first tried -7 = 1111 = 15. And that wraps around to +7. I even considered the possibility that the MSB was ignored for some reason but still no answer. The ONLY way I could get this answer was when i took the 2's complement of 1111 which is equal to +1(which is what the compiler also says). But I have no clue as to why this worked.

Comment: "-7 is a four bit number represented as 1111" -- that is true, if you would store signed integers as sign+value. On essentially all current hardware signed integers are stored as 2's complement (with `-7 = 111...111001`), and in C unsigned integers need to have wrap-around behavior, which is essentially equivalent to 2's complement. If you take the last 3 bits of an "unsigned -7", you get `001`.

Comment: In fact, a signed `1111` would typically be `-1` due to two's complement. If you do `(0) - (1)`, you'd expect `-1`, so try that in bit notation.

Comment: -7 (11111111111111111111111111111001) as 001 in the last 3bits is quite logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the C11 standard says, 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers paragraph 3:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
> repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type. 60)

The maximum of `a` is 7, so the value `7+1=8` is added or subtracted till it is in the range.
`-7+8=1` => `1` is stored.

`-7` in 2 complement is `(~7)+1` which is `(~0b111)+0b1 = 0b11111000+0b1 = 0b111111001` Store that in 3 bit and you get the last 3 bit of: `0b001=1`.

`0b1111` in a 4 bit signed number as 2 complement would be `-1`. Applying the 2 complement to it: `(~1)+1 = (~0b1)+0b1 = 0b1110+0b1 = 0b1111 = -1`.

You are correct that `0b1111` in a 4 bit signed number as signed magnitude would be 7, but nobody uses signed magnitude anymore, AFAIK it gets removed from C23 and only 2 complement will be allowed. And even on a signed magnitude system, the result will still be 1 because the the C standard requires it (as by the above mentioned paragraph)

Comment: Even on a signed magnitude machine, you get 1.  It's not about truncating the high bits as two of your paragraphs imply.

Comment: @ikegami i know that, should i add something so that this is more obvious?

Comment: Are you trying to say the spec's decision is (probably) based on the result of chopping off the high bits on a 2's complement machine? Could say that...

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This answer explains only why **your** system behaves as you observed. It does not claim to be correct for all systems. The standard requests no specific implementation for bit fields and on other systems the outcome can be completely different.*

An unsigned integer of 3 bits width can take only these 8 different values:

| decimal | binary |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 000 |
| 1 | 001 |
| 2 | 010 |
| 3 | 011 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | 101 |
| 6 | 110 |
| 7 | 111 |

Now you assign -7 to such an integer. As all integer expressions (except wider types) are implicitly calculated as `int`, most probably as two's complement and with 32 bits width on your machine, the binary value is 0b11111111111111111111111111111001.

Since the compiler realizes the assignment by truncating the width to the target type, only the lowest 3 bits are stored: 0b001. This is 1 as decimal.

Comment: It is only coincidental that this explanation matches the observation.  The behavior of storing an out-of-range value in an object having unsigned integer type is defined in terms of the semantic value stored and the type's limits, *not* in terms of the value's representation.  The result must be the same regardless of the representation of the value assigned -- on sign / magnitude machines too, for example (if you could find one).